# Understanding MySQL's slow query log format

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm reading MySQL's slow query log and it's:

```
# Time: 141004 12:30:47
# User@Host: dbuser[dbuser] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:  1959
# Query_time: 0.017325  Lock_time: 0.000112 Rows_sent: 75  Rows_examined: 22146
SET timestamp=1412413247;
SELECT ...
```

It's in the case that I didn't set any `long_query_time` in `my.cnf` which means it's set to default; `10` seconds. And I confirmed that using MySQL Workbench. So my question is why is this query logged as a slow one? It took less than 2/100 of a second!

BTW, I'm using MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Is the line `log-queries-not-using-indexes` in my.cnf uncommented?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to check if MySQL logging queries that are slow or not but running without using indexes:

```
show variables like 'log_queries_not_using_indexes'
```